# Which of the following functions is quasiconvex?

Tags: convex-geometry

a) $F(x)=x^{2}$

b) $F(x)=e^{-x}$

c) $F(x)=\cos (x)$

d) $F(x)=x^{-1}$ if $f\neq  0$ and $f=0$ if $x=0$

Hi, i am finding quasi concavity and convexity very difficult to understand.
Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: Sources available on the internet explaining this topic is very confusing, is there any simple source known to anyone?

Comment: Do you know what "quasiconvex" means?

Comment: I read about it, pretty confusing stuff. And the tests available fr checking it does not seem very practical.

Comment: As a first step I think it would help if you write explicitly what it means for a function to be quasiconvex.

Answer (score 0):

All convex functions are surely quasiconvex so for $f(x)=x^2$ the second derivative is 2 >0 so it is convex. Giving us that A is quasiconvex.
C) cosx   Changes from being convex to concave and back every $\pi$ period starting at an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: A is convex because $f''(x)=2>0$ ?

Comment: Even for (B) $f''(x)=\frac{1}{e^{x}}$ is $>0$ ? so isn't it convex?

Comment: yeah, but wouldn't that make B quasi convex as well? How do we differentiate between the two?

Comment: Sorry if my questions are silly, but i'm just having a difficult time wrapping my head around these.

Comment: Yes, B is quasiconvex and your resoning is correct.

Comment: Thanks! But it's a multiple choice question so we need to pick one

Answer (score 0):

The function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be **Quasi-convex** function if its domain and all its sublevel sets as:

$$S_\alpha = \{\mathbf{x}| \mathbf{x}\in \text{dom}f, f(x) \leq \alpha\}$$

are **convex sets** for every $\alpha$. Means, if you draw a horizontal line for any $\alpha$ then the corresponding domain for $f(x) \leq \alpha$ should be a convex set.

Notice: Any convex function is quasiconvex.

Here:

$x^2$ is a convex function and hence is a quasiconvex function.

$e^{-x}$ is a convex function and hence is a quasiconvex function.

$\cos x$ is not a quasi convex function for $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$.

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ with $f(0) = 0$ is not a quasiconvex function.

Notice that from optimization view point the $e^{-x}$ is unsolvable objectve function where: the optimal value is $p^{\star} = 0$ but no exact optimum point $x$ for that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that any convex (concave) function is quasiconvex (quasiconcave), but the converse may or may not be true.

Let $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in C^2$. Then $f$ is quasiconvex (or quasiconcave) if $|B_r|\leq0$ (or$(-1)^r|B_r|\geq0$) for $r=1,2,...,n,$ where $B_r$ is the bordered Hessian matrix: $$B_r=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} & f_{x_2} & ... & f_{x_r} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} & f_{x_1x_2} & ... & f_{x_1x_r} \\
        . & . & .  & ... & . \\
        f_{x_r} & f_{x_rx_1} & f_{x_rx_2} & ... & f_{x_rx_r} \\
        \end{pmatrix}.$$

Note: Sometimes the above rules do not work. Then one must check the other rule:
$f$ is quasiconvex (quasiconcave) for $x\in(a,b)$ if $f(x)\le \max(f(a),f(b))   \  \  (f(x)\ge \min (f(a),f(b))$.

a) For $f(x)=x^2$,

$|B_1|=\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & 2x \\
        2x & 2 \\
        \end{vmatrix} =-4x^2\le0$. Thus, it is quasiconvex.

$(-1)^1|B_1|=-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & 2x \\
        2x & 2 \\
        \end{vmatrix} =4x^2\ge0$. Thus, it is quasiconcave for $x\in(a,b)$ if $f(x)$ is monotonous.

b) For $f(x)=e^{-x}$,

$|B_1|=\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & -e^{-x} \\
        -e^{-x} & e^{-x} \\
        \end{vmatrix} =-e^{-2x}\le0$. Thus, it is quasiconvex.

$(-1)^1|B_1|=-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & -e^{-x} \\
        -e^{-x} & e^{-x} \\
        \end{vmatrix} =e^{-2x}\ge0$. Thus, it is also quasiconcave as well.

c) For $f(x)=\cos{x}$,

$|B_1|=\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & -\sin{x} \\
        -\sin{x} & -\cos{x} \\
        \end{vmatrix} =-\sin^2{x}\le0$. Thus, it is quasiconvex for $x\in(a,b)$ if $f(x)\le \max(f(a),f(b)) $.

$(-1)^1|B_1|=-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & -\sin{x} \\
        -\sin{x} & -\cos{x} \\
        \end{vmatrix} =\sin^2{x}\ge0$. Thus, it is quasiconcave for $x\in(a,b)$ if $f(x)\ge \min(f(a),f(b)) $.

d) For $f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x},  \ if \  x\ne0 \\ 
0,    \ if  \ x=0
\end{cases}
$,

$|B_1|=\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & -\frac{1}{x^2} \\
        -\frac{1}{x^2} & \frac{2}{x^3} \\
        \end{vmatrix} =-\frac{1}{x^4}\leq0$. Thus, it is quasiconvex.

$(-1)^1|B_1|=-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & f_{x_1} \\
        f_{x_1} & f_{x_1x_1} \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 
-\begin{vmatrix}
        0 & -\frac{1}{x^2} \\
        -\frac{1}{x^2} & \frac{2}{x^3} \\
        \end{vmatrix} =\frac{1}{x^4}\geq0$. Thus, it is quasiconcave.